# Error propagation with Log base 10

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, experimental-technique, data-analysis

I have some data and some errors for the data. The task I have been given is to $\log_{10}$ both sets of data, and then deal with the errors to plot a graph. For natural logarithms, this is easier as (I believe) you can use $\sigma_f = \sigma_x / x$ for $f = \ln(x)$ however I am struggling to find any formula/guidance on how to propagate the errors for none-natural logs.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Unfortunately, we do not answer homework-question.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: very sorry about leaving the homework tag off, did not realise this was a thing. Many thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I ... don’t see how this is a homework question, in the way we usually define them. It’s perhaps more of a mathematical question than a physics question, but the way physicists deal with uncertainty analysis is different enough from (and, imho, better enough than) other fields that I personally prefer to leave error-analysis questions open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you seem to already know, if you have a function such as $$f(x) = \ln{x},$$ then we can simply differentiate the above equation to get that: $$\text{d}f = \frac{\text{d}x}{x} \quad \quad \implies \quad \quad \Delta f \approx \frac{\Delta x}{x},$$ where in the last step I have assumed that the errors are sufficiently small so that the differentials $\text{d}f$ and $\text{d}x$ can be safely "replaced" by the absolute errors $\Delta f$ and $\Delta x$ respectively. (Such a calculus-based approach to error-analysis is useful, and you can read up more about it [here](https://www.lockhaven.edu/%7Edsimanek/scenario/errorman/calculus.htm).)

Now, if you instead have $$f(x) = \log_{10}(x),$$ the method is identical, the only thing you need to know is a standard result from logarithms, that: $$\log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln{10}}.$$ As a result, $$\Delta f = \frac{1}{\ln 10}\frac{\Delta x}{x}.$$

---

As @rob points out in the comments below, it is important to stress that this holds true only when $\Delta x\ll x$. If this is no longer true, then the error bars will be asymmetric, and different methods will have to be employed to deal with individual situations. As pointed out in @EmilioPisanty's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/95278/157014), if $\Delta x = x$ (in a "worst case" scenario), then the value of $x$ could be anything between $0$ and $2x$, meaning that the error in $\ln(x)$ could be anything between $-\infty$ and $\ln(2x)$, which is clearly not symmetric about the point $\ln(x)$!

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful

Comment: Since the asker is making plots, an additional note: if the fractional errors $\Delta x/x$ are *not* small, the error bars on the log plot will be asymmetric.

Comment: @rob Oh! Yes, I didn't notice that the question mentioned plots. That is true, and also not at all obvious. I'll add a note in my answer.