# How do you do error propagation for Logarithmic equations?

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

my equation is a=10log_10(x/10^-12). I have the error value for a, but I'm struggling to propagate the error for x

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95254/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619143/2451 and links therein.